# CAP CDS modules(solid)

Tags: node.js, solid, sap-cap

structuct project similar solid
[image]

without path /db

error

> ```
>    Error: "src/modules/logs/logs-service.cds": could not create a compile unit for the file [8211714]
>         at "src/modules/logs/logs-service.cds" (0:0)
>    Error: Could not find a ".hdiconfig" file in "src/modules/logs" or in any parent folder [8212808]
>    Error: Adding "src/modules/logs/logs-service.cds" for deploy... failed [8211700]
>    Error: Preparing... failed [8211602]
>       Make failed (5 errors, 0 warnings): tried to deploy 4 files, undeploy 0 files, redeploy 0 dependent files
>    Error: Making... failed [8211605]
>    Error: Starting make in the container "C0E6F76252B84645810EECC57BF039D1" with 4 files to deploy, 0 files to undeploy... failed [8214168]
>    Deployment to container C0E6F76252B84645810EECC57BF039D1 failed - error: HDI make failed [Deployment ID: none].
>    Deployment ended at 2024-02-02 19:06:00
>    Error: HDI make failed
> ```

repo project: https://github.com/luizcarlospedrosogomes/cap-cds-modules

Is it possible to continue with this structure?